# Auto-forwarding Meeting planners as invites not attachments

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, rules

All,
I have setup a rule where for any message I get that is a of type "meeting invitation or update" to forward it to another email address (SharePoint Calendar).
However, rather than it being forwarded as a meeting invite, it gets sent as an attachment to an email which SharePoint cannot decipher.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Exchange account, set up the rule to **redirect** the message rather than forwarding it.

Note that there is a difference between redirecting and forwarding emails - when an email is redirected, it arrives to the new recipient just like it would have arrived to the original recipient.

Comment: Thanks Garrulinae, however the rule sends the invite as an attachment to an email rather than how a meeting forward would be sent. SharePoint is having difficulty processing this email with attachment. This is where my issue is.